# Cannot access a specific remote IP address on Mac Os X 10.7.5

Tags: macos, network, vpn

I cannot reach a certain remote IP address from my Mac. Pinging it gives "Request timeout" and after 4 or 5 pings "No route to host" and "Host is down". 
The weird fact is that other Macs on my same local network can access it without problems.
I don't have any firewall active, nor Little Snitch or similar, nor proxies, nor /etc/hosts tricks (which deal only with host name resolutions, anyway, but I have to reach the IPv4 address).
I have a 2011 13" MacBook Air with OS X 10.7.5.
Can you point me to some other obscure network settings or blocking lists that may be active on Mac Os X or maybe some software that may interfere with network settings?
Thank you.

Comment: Did you try a traceroute?

Comment: yep. same result:

`1  * *traceroute: sendto: No route to host

traceroute: wrote 5.xx.xx.xx 52 chars, ret=-1
 *

traceroute: sendto: Host is down

 2 traceroute: wrote 5.xx.xx.xx 52 chars, ret=-1

 *traceroute: sendto: Host is down

traceroute: wrote 5.xx.xx.xx 52 chars, ret=-1

 *traceroute: sendto: Host is down

traceroute: wrote 5.xx.xx.xx 52 chars, ret=-1`

Comment: What kind of host are you connecting to? Is it public or local to your network? Did you ever configure custom routes on your machine in the past? Did you reboot your computer in the meanwhile? What does a traceroute output on the other computers?

Comment: The host is public, as I said. I didn't configure any custom routes, not that I'm aware of (don't know if some apps could have made it without letting me know, and I don't know how to check). Of course I did reboot (...). Traceroute on another Mac on my same local network gives a correct output, i.e.


`1  192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1)  1.210 ms  0.734 ms  0.714 ms
 2  10.163.176.1 (10.163.176.1)  7.484 ms  7.699 ms *
 3  10.1.105.114 (10.1.105.114)  8.210 ms  6.581 ms  6.819 ms`

...and so on...

Comment: needless to say, pinging and tracerouting other public ip addresses works perfectly.

Comment: found it. it was LogMeIn causing the issue. I'll answer my own question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies on the LogMeIn Hamachi network which, on IPv4, tries to get all the 5.0.0.0/8 netblock even if there are classes opf public IP addresses in there.
Solved by setting LogMeIn to use IPv6 only.

See:

http://community.logmein.com/t5/Hamachi/Hamachi-and-the-5-0-0-0-8-netblock/td-p/55826

and

http://community.logmein.com/t5/Hamachi/5-x-x-x-Address-Range/td-p/83996